# Package uses conflict org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor

Tags: spring, osgi, rcp, equinox, maven-bundle-plugin

In my project, I am getting package uses conflict with spring bundles. I used the techniques given in this link

http://njbartlett.name/2011/09/02/uses-constraints.html

I am getting package uses conflict for this:

```
initial@reference:file:../../../my_project_maven/my_project/myproject-core/ [2158]
  Package uses conflict: Import-Package:org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor; version="2.5.6"
```

I seached for bundles exporting org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor; version="2.5.6" and found this:

```
osgi> p org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor; version="2.5.6"<org.springframework_2.5.6 [2201]>
osgi>
```

So I opened up the springframework jar and saw the uses for the exported package and found these

```
javax.persistence,
javax.persistence.spi,
oracle.toplink.essentials.sessions,
org.apache.openjpa.persistence,
org.eclipse.persistence.sessions,
org.hibernate,
org.springframework.dao,
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource,
org.springframework.orm.jpa,
org.springframework.transaction
```

Out of the above, the only ones that my core bundle is importing are

```
javax.persistence;version="1.0.0"
org.springframework.dao;version="2.5.6"
org.springframework.orm.jpa;version="2.5.6"
```

Springframework is importing javax.persistence version of 1.0.0 and my core bundle is also importing 1.0.0 so there are no version conflicts there. Also these imports

```
org.springframework.dao;version="2.5.6"

org.springframework.orm.jpa;version="2.5.6"
```

are exports from springframework bundle, so no version conflicts there too.

There are no version conflicts in the org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor package uses and the imports in my core bundle. I do not understand what is causing this package uses conflict. Is there an easy way of debugging these?

Comment: You do not say which OSGi container you use. In my experience, Felix gives pretty clear error messages about package uses conflict while Equinox does not provide enough information. Also, I had an issue with Equinox and I could not find out the cause as it seemed that there was only one package from everything and after switching to Felix the problem went away. What I am suggesting is to try to reproduce the issue with Felix (if you have the chance) and paste the log here. It will tell exactly which package is doubled and how it is wired from two directions.

Comment: I use equinox and run my RCP app from elipse PDE. I use many core equinox bundles and eclipse bundles in my app, so not sure how I can switch to felix.

Comment: Based on equinox logs it is really hard to find out the root cause of the problem. I normally have issue with the javax.transaction package. It is available in  the the JDK and from in a bundle as well. While one of the bundle wires to the package in the JDK, the other one wires to the package that comes from the bundle. Probably you have the same issue.

Comment: I solved this issue. javax packages were the culprits. In one of the plugins I was using Required-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime. It had javax.* packages dependencies and I explicitly declared another version of javax.* package. So it was giving out package uses conflict. I got rid of required-bundle and used Import Packages. It made my life lot easier. Thanks for the pointer though.